# Is it possible to send an event from one component to another without using a global EventBus in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components that do not have a parent - child relationship. They are not related to each other. But I am trying to make it so that when an event is emitted from one component then the other component can listen to that event and perform an action.

Here is an example, let's say that I have a component called "reset-component" and at some point it will emit an event called "reset".

```
<reset-component @reset="actionReset" />
```

And I also have a "grid-component" that should listen to the "reset" action emitted by the "reset-component" and perform some action.

```
<grid-component />
```

What are my options do accomplish this? The only solution that I can think of is to emit a global event using an EventBus and then have the grid-component listen to that global event. But is that a good idea? Isn't that more of an anti-patern?

```
// Reset component
EventBus.$emit('reset')

// Grid component
created()
{
    EventBus.$on('reset', () => {
        doSomething()
    })
}
```

Comment: Consider using Vuex (Global state manager) to avoid issues like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Subject** to accomplish this. See this link for more information: [Vue.js + RxJS - Communicating Between Components with Observable & Subject](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/02/vuejs-rxjs-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: That is kind of the same idea as a global Event emitter/listener

Answer (score 0):

You actually have multiple options. But as you already answered yourself a global event bus is one of them

In your main file (assume something like main.js) you could do

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue()
```

By doing so you can now access `this.$bus` in every component e.g.

```
methods: {
  dispatchReset () {
    this.$bus.$emit('reset')
  }
}
```

And other components can listen to it via

```
created () {
  this.$bus.$on('reset', this.doReset)
}
```

Vuex is another option that was already mentioned by @Armen Armus in the comments. You could hold a global state for your application and dispatch events from within every component you want. However, if you really only want a few events like a reset I don't see a reason to add vuex.

Another option could also be to simply hold a "state" in your root Vue instance / component, but this would require you do pass down props and pass up events from within every view / component - and that would be quite annoying.

Comment: I agree, my app is so small that there is no reason to bring in a big library like Vuex so I was looking for alternatives. So looks like the only real viable option is a global Bus..

Comment: Is there any issue with a global event bus?

Comment: I have heard that it's called an anti-pattern because it is difficult to understand where events are coming from with a global Event Bus.

Answer (score 0):

When passing props to child components and emitting events to parent components become hard because of distance or app complexity you can use VueX :
https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Well my app is very small so I didn't want to bring in a big library like Vuex for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add to the instances hooks:

`ResetComponent.$on("reset", doSmth)`

[vm.$on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on)

But i guess this will create a relation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `vm.$on` and `vm.$emit` within components.

In your `reset-component` trigger the event from any method or element

`this.$emit('reset')`

and then you can then listen it,

`<reset-component @reset="actionReset" />`